# C# on event start, start another event

Tags: c#, events

i want if an picture is clicked to start a button click event. 
But how?
ButtonPlus gains by hitting +1 everytime, if reached 5/10... it activates annother image.

to increase wasting time by hitting the plus button, i want to click the image, for example the first(get value 5) and doing the button_click code.

i have thought by setting the ButtonPlus value on 4, and forwarding to the button_click event it gets to value 5, and doing the switch.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MaxPunkte > 0)
        {

            if (ButtonPlus1 < 30)
            {
                ButtonPlus1 += 1;
                MaxPunkte += -1;
                LabelAnzeige1 = ButtonPlus1;

                label1.Text = LabelAnzeige1.ToString();
                label5.Text = MaxPunkte.ToString();
                label7.Text = (LabelAnzeige1 * 10).ToString();
                label8.Text = label7.Text;
                #region Switch
                switch (ButtonPlus1)
                {
                    case 5:

                        pictureBox1.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonSmall_5_active;
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        pictureBox2.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonBig_10_active_empty;
                        break;

                    case 15:

                        pictureBox3.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonSmall_15_active;
                        break;

                    case 20:
                        pictureBox4.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonBig_20_active_empty;
                        break;

                    case 25:

                        pictureBox5.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonSmall_25_active;
                        break;

                    case 30:
                        pictureBox6.Image = TraitCalc.Resources.HexagonBig_30_active_empty;
                        break;


                }
                #endregion

            }
        }

    }

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonPlus1 = 4;
        //and start button click event (adds +1 = 5 -> go to switch case 1)


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not directly call the button handler?

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonPlus1 = 4;
    //and start button click event (adds +1 = 5 -> go to switch case 1)
    button1_Click(null, null); // or whatever arguments you need, 
                               // but you were not using them.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Move the button click code into a separate method
- Call this method from the button click event
- Also call it from the picture click event

(Or you can literally call `button1_Click` like any other method.)